# Description of Scipy matrix - Sklearn

Tags: python, sklearn-pandas

I'm working on NPL with sklearn, slipt my data set into training and test sets as follow:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,Y,test_size=0.3, shuffle=True,random_state=0,stratify=Y)
```

How I can get a description of the X_train and y_train (i.e. how many registers has of each label), due that the resulting objects are class 'scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix' and does not have a description attribute.

Answer (score 0):

[`csr_matrix` is a sparse matrix provided by `scipy`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html). If you want to inspect its content, you could call [`.toarray()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.toarray.html#scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.toarray) on it, which return a dense ndarray representation of this matrix.

For example, `print(X_train.toarray())`